# Laravel Private Channel Not Authorizing : Error 404

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to build a real-time notification system. I used Laravel-Notifications and laravel-echo-server. when I listen for notification using start command in terminal laravel-echo-server start then error occured in private channel:

> Client can not be authenticated, got HTTP status 404 ⚠ [6:57:15 PM] -
>   qXY1YTBcnGUzqJvfAAAB could not be authenticated to private-App.User.2

Client can not be authenticated, got HTTP status 404

CODE

**channels.php**

```
Broadcast::channel('App.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
 return (int) $user->user_id === (int) $id;
});
```

**Notification**

```
class StickBoardLiked extends Notification
{
use Queueable;

protected $boardid;


/**
 * Create a new notification instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($boardid)
{
    $this->boardid = $boardid;
}

/**
 * Get the notification's delivery channels.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['database', 'broadcast'];
}

/**
 * Get the mail representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
 */
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
                ->line('The introduction to the notification.')
                ->action('Notification Action', url('/'))
                ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
}

/**
 * Get the array representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function toArray($notifiable)
{
    return [
        //
        'liked_by' => Auth::user()->user_id,
        'username' => Auth::user()->user_name,
        'board_id' => $this->boardid,
        'content_type' => 'like',

    ];
}
}
```

**front-end script to listen for notification**

```
Echo.private("App.User." + this.user.user_id).notification(notification 
=> {
  this.unreadNotifications.push(notification);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this, Error was in path the larvel echo was going.

It was

> http://localhost

and was to be

> http://localhost:8000

Comment: what do you mean by path?